# How do I subtract pixels from numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the height of the footer by finding out the height of another div.

I'm using the `.css("height")` function, but I can't get the function to return the answer in pixels.

Here's the code I'm using. It's returning `NaN`.

```
if($("#middleContainer").height() > 500){
  var add_height = $("#middleContainer").css("height") - 500;
  alert(add_height);
}
```

After looking at the suggestions, I'm using the following code. It doesn't make any difference.

```
if($("#middleContainer").height() > 500){
  var add_height = $("#middleContainer").height() - 500;
  var new_height = -850 + add_height;
  alert(new_height);
  $(".footer").css("top", "new_height");
}
```

Comment: Why not using `.height()` method: `$("#middleContainer").height()`?

Comment: `$(".footer").css("top", new_height);` `new_height` as variable, not string. And for readability, consider to use: `var new_height = add_height - 850;`, you aren't Yoda, are you? ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff haha no I am not. :P However, I made the change, and it's still not working.

Comment: You should provide any online sample where your issue can be checked, as e.g a jsFiddle. FYI, to set `top` property of an element, element must not be statically positionned (`static` position by default). So maybe your issue is regarding this, try e.g: `.footer { position: relative; }`

Comment: Here's the link jsfiddle.net/dgvhgr6x/

It's an ebay template. I want the footer to resize if the middleContainer is bigger than 500px.

Comment: It works as expected, check the `.footer` DIV position

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. The .footer div position doesn't get changed using the if statement.

Comment: Infact, even when I changed the top property directly, it didn't change. if($("#middleContainer").height() > 500){
 $(".footer").css("top", "-850px");
}

Comment: The position of `.footer` DIV changes, see: http://jsfiddle.net/dgvhgr6x/1/

Comment: Okay, I can see that. Thanks.

The new problem I'm facing is that the footer overlaps the content. See http://jsfiddle.net/dgvhgr6x/8/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

Following code return height with string type so you have to parse as Int

```
var add_height = parseInt($("#middleContainer").css("height")) - 500;
// Return as String data type value
```

This code return number so do not want to parse as Int it directly works

```
var add_height = $("#middleContainer").height();
// Return as Number data type value
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
parseInt( $("#middleContainer").css("height"));
```

Comment: @A.Wolff That's strange.  Both previous experience and the jQuery documentation say it should.

Comment: The difference between `.css( "height" )` and `.height()` is that the latter returns a unit-less **pixel** value

Comment: @Archer The DOC says it returns the computed style, so it is expected behaviour: `Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).`

Comment: @A.Wolff Fair enough - I stand corrected in that case.  I always believed it retained the unit type.

Comment: @Archer Ya, i was not sure about it, so still good to remember it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is always in pixeis, you just need to parse it

```
var h =$(something).height() - 500;
$('something').height(h);
```

Comment: `height()` returns number, no need for parseInt